# How to use body request express

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I want to access to the body to my request but he is empty. I use a body-Parser but I don't know why I haven't data in my body.

```js
import express from 'express';
import * as bodyParser from 'body-parser';

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
const port = 3000;

app.post('/', (request, response) => {
  response.send(request.body);
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`you can run the server on http://localhost:${ port }`);
});
```

result:

```
{}
```

for my request I use postman

[image]

so I don't understand, I read other topic or forums and he this is the same code.

Comment: what are you sending in the body?, if you don't send anything, it's clear that you'll receive an empty object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`body-parser` uses the `Content-Type` header to determine how the body will be parsed. My immediate suspicion (because I've done the same thing before) is that you may not be passing the `Content-Type` header - for example, if you are trying to use JSON, you need to be sending `Content-Type: application/json` on your POST request.

Comment: i replaceContent-Type:  text/plain for Content-Type: application/json but I have an error ```SyntaxError: Unexpected token ’ in JSON at position 82```

Comment: That means bodyParser is now properly parsing your JSON but there's an error in what you have sent. I can see an errant ' at the end of your JSON in your screenshot.

Comment: It's because of the `'` that you added at the end of the json in line 6.